# multiprocessing and write date to disk to reduce memory costs in python?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, networkx

I am using `multiprocessing` to do a bunch of parallel computing, and returning the results as a list. The may issue right now is the function often runs out of memory. My current code is like

```
def some_func(a)
  b = a**2 (some calculations here)
  return b

with multiprocessing.Pool() as p:
   results_list = p.map(partial(some_func), a_list_of_a)

with open(f"results/final_data.pkl", "wb") as f:
   pickle.dump(results_list, f)
```

I think one solution might be split the `a_list_of_a` into several batches, and write the results as batches to the disk to reduce the memory usage. Is it possible?

Edited:

The main issue of my `some_func` is it returns a large variable. A `networkx` graph, specifically. The input `a_list_a` is a list of node numbers. And the return of `some_func` is graphs generated by given nodes. The length of `a_list_of_a` is around 15,000. My memory is 64GB but the function is still killed due to out of memory.

Maybe there is a better way to store `networkx` `Graph`? I do need to keep the nodes' attribute when storing the `Graph` object.

Comment: Why pay the cost to transfer content back to the parent process instead of have the child write it to disk directly? You can avoid multiprocessing's overhead if you have the child stream directly to storage.

Comment: Note that `pickle` can be faster to load, but it is slower to write and larger.

Comment: And is there any reason to read in your entire a_list_of_a data before you start?

Comment: A lot of the details depend on what "some calculations here" _are_. A lot of operations can be posed in a way that lets one operate against an indexed database; those are _designed_ to operate on datasets larger-than-RAM by nature. And of course if you can move work out of Python altogether and make a database server do it on that end, all the better.

Comment: The pool process could write to disk, perhaps using a different file format like a db or hdf or something so that a single target still gets all of the data.

Comment: How big are the results? Can you run this with dummy same-sized local results? I am a bit surprised that code that looks like this would fail due to the `multiprocessing` portion.

Comment: You could also use Pool.imap or Pool.imap_unordered (and use a small chunksize like `chunksize=16`) to write incrementally. You'd likely need something different than pickle.

Comment: And why `partial(some_func)` and not just `some_func`?

Comment: @Cireo - If the result is much bigger than the input, you could have a problem like this.

Comment: https://github.com/plasma-umass/scalene is great for profiling CPU and memory usage and explicitly works with multiprocessing.  might be worth figuring out which part of your computation is using up your memory before going too far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## memory measurements

You want to get a much better feel for how memory is being consumed,
and being released.
The example `some_func` clearly allocates far less RAM than your "real" function does.

---

## file format

Consider using a more portable data format than pickle().
For example, CSV or JSONL, or an RDBMS,
or binary format like Parquet <del>or HDF5</del>.
The trouble with pickle is, if you rev library versions,
it's easy to wind up with unreadable binary files.
And even if it *is* readable, you have to read *everything*,
including large objects you might not need ATM.

---

## the child should serialize results

```
   results_list = p.map(partial(some_func), a_list_of_a)
```

Here, you're sending a "large" result object over a pipe to the parent,
which allocates storage for it and then sends it to the filesystem.
Much better to have each child do the FS I/O work and return a "done!" indicator.
Name the files according the child's PID, or perhaps according to
an input data hash.

You didn't really describe what "A" is,
nor whether `some_func` takes a microsecond or a minute.
There's overhead incurred at each pipeline stage,
so consider batching the input tasks into some convenient size.
That might correspond to taking between 1 .. 10 seconds of processing time.

---

## map() makes promises you don't need

Consider using
[.imap_unordered()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.imap_unordered) instead.
If you don't care about the order, and don't care *when*
something happens as long as it happens, then give
the `multiprocessing` module some scheduling flexibility;
do not unduly constrain it.

It's possible you'll need a post-processing phase to assemble results
to put them in some required order, and that's fine.
It may well take fewer elapsed minutes to complete all that.

Comment: would suggest against using HDF5 with multiprocessing, default builds don't allow the file to be opened by different processes (i.e. you need a specific parallel hdf5 build and even then it can only be used in specific ways).  I've had a lot more luck with SQLite for these tasks, you need to set a few [pragmas](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html) for it to behave sensibly (it bends over backwards for compatibility by default) but it's a very impressive bit of engineering

Comment: @SamMason, granted, thank you. I think I had in mind that it could make a good post-processing output format, with children creating unique HDF5 filenames. Better to keep the answer simple, I suppose. I updated it to reflect your sage advice.

Comment: lots of little files kind of goes against how I've seen HDF5 being used, but that would certainly work here.  that said it often happens that multiple steps want to share intermediate results which kind of breaks that way of using HDF5 and the file naming/separation convention gets very tied up with the details of the algorithms.  having an RDBMS (or something else with atomic updates) often simplifies things later

Comment: If order matters in the returned calculations, then use `imap` instead of `imap_unordered`. In either case you should probably be using the *chunksize* argument. `map` in your case is using a default *chunksize* of `ceil(len(a_list_of_a) / (4 * multiprocessing.cpu_count()))`. Use a smaller value if memory is still an issue.